# Sum up 'remaining' that pie chart is more readable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem. I want to plot a pie chart. But unfortunately only three `id`s are readable. The other have a just to small part. Is there an option to summary, all the small ones and sum up then with the name `remaining`? Is there also an option to that automatically? Because I can say the limit is 100, 1000 etc. but is there an option to sum up automatically. I am using in my real dataframe `df.value_counts()`

Dataframe

```py
   id  count
0   1   4521
1   2   1247
2   3    962
3   4     12
4   5      6
5   6      5
6   7      4
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     'count': [4521, 1247, 962, 12, 6, 5, 4],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

colors = sns.color_palette('GnBu_r')
plt.pie(df['count'], 
        labels = df['id'], colors = colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine rows in your data with a condition: if the `'percentage'` is less than a threshold, then sum up those rows:

```
threshold = 0.1
df['percentage'] = df['count']/df['count'].sum()

remaining = df.loc[df['percentage'] < threshold].sum(axis = 0)
remaining.loc['id'] = 'remaining'
df = df[df['percentage'] >= threshold]

df = df.append(remaining, ignore_index = True)
df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)
```

So you get:

```
          id  count  percentage
0          1   4521    0.669084
1          2   1247    0.184549
2          3    962    0.142371
3  remaining     27    0.003996
```

### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

threshold = 0.1

d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     'count': [4521, 1247, 962, 12, 6, 5, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['percentage'] = df['count']/df['count'].sum()

remaining = df.loc[df['percentage'] < threshold].sum(axis = 0)
remaining.loc['id'] = 'remaining'
df = df[df['percentage'] >= threshold]

df = df.append(remaining, ignore_index = True)
df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)

colors = sns.color_palette('GnBu_r')
plt.pie(df['count'],
        labels = df['id'], colors = colors)
plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it.